# what is the value of $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{x^n}dx$, x is a natural number.

Tags: integration

Integrate, $$I_n=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{x^n}dx$$

Let n=1

$$I_1=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{x}dx$$

Comment: Do you mean $ \ n \ $ is a natural number?

Answer (score 1):

None of these integrals integrate across 0.  None of these integrals exist.